# Chat-like UI premade?

Tags: pythonanywhere

I want to make a custom textual interactive UI, akin to that used by ChatGPT - is there an existing example of this (in Flask, Django, I'm agnostic reallt) ? Beyond supporting multiple users, I'd like to capture the session text in some kind of datastore. I don't want to reinvent the wheel - I found this tutorial, but I wonder if there was anything closer to the ChatGPT dialogue experience pre-made, that I could just hook my colab logic into. Googling ChatGPT chat tends to throw up people programming chat bots using GPT, or implementing IM clones using GPT to program them.

https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/169/

Cheers,
Winton

Comment: I found this flet based UI, but I cant find any examples of how to import it into PythonAnywher https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-chatgpt-clone-in-python/